# Why will this password hash and compare not work?

Tags: php

The way I am hashing the password and inserting values into the database,

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (username, email, password, type, gender, joined)
                      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$q -> execute(array($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], 
                    hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . date('y/m/d')), 
                    $_POST['type'], $_POST['gender'], date('y/m/d')));
```

When I compare then like this,

```
if ($count == 1 
&& $info['password'] === hash('sha256', $_POST['password'].$info['joined'])
&& $info['logcount'] != -1)
```

Both the hashes work but throw out different values? I am using the exact same formula for creating and comparing.

I am taking the user password, salting it with the current date, then hashing, both values are stored in the database and on comparison doing the exact same thing, all the tutorials online are all about hashing and creating secure hashes, not comparing.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What type is `joined`? If it's MySQL and you're using DATE, then it will print out as "YYYY-MM-DD". It's very likely that your salt differs. You may want to use a more foolproof way to salt the password.

Possible solutions:

1. Make `joined` a string (VARCHAR in MySQL). That works, but is less efficient and won't allow you to easily sort/search by the date.
2. Match the date precisely as your SQL implementation uses it. for MySQL, for example, use YYYY-MM-DD. Also, create the date string up front, don't call `date('y/m/d')` twice in your query. Create a variable up front with the date (like "2011-04-21"), use it for the salt, pass it into `joined`, and that should do.
3. Use the UNIX_TIMESTAMP to turn the date into a number. No formatting necessary with that.

Comment: I was told on here to use the date as a salt? This subject has so many opinions it is hard to come to one that I see.

Comment: would you be so kind to share your method for salting, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Two things: 1. Grab the date beforehand, 2. Use a string for "joined", OR use a format that you know matches your specific SQL implementation exactly.

Comment: Rather than depending on the date format returned from the db, just reformat the date into your preferred format: `date('y/m/d', strtotime($info['joined']))`.

Comment: That, or use the UNIX_TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 2):

I'll guess the `joined` column in the database is a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column? If so, you're probably not getting the date back formatted as `y/m/d`, but `Y-m-d` or even `Y-m-d H:i:s`. You'll need to reformat it to get the same value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing `joined` as something other than a `varchar` type, then the value you get from the database may not match the value returned from the `date()` function.

Either store `joined` as plain-text or use a value that you can extract both from the `date()` and the database.